# How to display Metaobject selected value in shipify?

Tags: html, json, shopify, liquid, metaobject

I have 2 metaobject "Faqs Category" and "Faqs List"
In "Faqs List" I have added Metaobject "Category" Field selected with "Faqs Category"

How to display selected category value by liquid code?

Here you can check the category list - https://prnt.sc/u0WF1EsMcYxQ

```
<div class="faq_list">
    {% for faqitem in shop.metaobjects.faqs_list.values %}
    <div class="faq_item" data-title="{{ faqitem.faqs_category.value }}">
       <div class="faq_title">{{ faqitem.title }}</div>
          <div class="faq_content">
            <div class="content">{{ faqitem.content | metafield_tag }}</div>
          </div>
       </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Title and content working fine but Category name not working can you please help me on this?